# How to put facebook login button in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am using Facebook sdk 4.3.0 and it is working all fine. I have made my login activity and that's really working nice. Now due to some requirements I want to show the user a alert dialog saying to please sign in. And for this I have to show the alert dialog with one button and that button should be of facebook login button. The dialog should be look like [this](http://imagehosting.io/image/vTx).

I know how to implement login button in Activity but tell Me how to implement it in alert dialog. Please help . Share any link or code .

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-alert-dialog/). It will help you how to create a custom dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Dialog with a custom layout. It is described in the official developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: I dont think so this links helps me